# Linked list (utlist.h) - question how to remove few objects from list in C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

Hi all I have a question about LL from utlist.h in C.

node of list looks for example like below:

```
typedef struct node_list_t
{
    node_list_t* next;
    uint8_t surname_nbr;
    uint8_t name_nbr;
    uint8_t age;
}  node_list_t;
```

In my programm I have implemented a list with for example 200 nodes. I have to remove all nodes which "surname_nbr == 23;" 
What is the best way to do this in C using utlist.h ?

Comment: "In my programm I have implemented a list with for example 200 nodes." best to post the relevant parts of that code and also what you have tried to remove a few objects from list.  [mcve]  else this is too broad.

Comment: What library is `utlist.h` from? Read its documentation.

Comment: Do you have code to remove an arbitrary single node from the list? Then iterate over the list, and as soon as you find a suitable node call the function to remove that node.

Comment: I'm using implemantation of https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash